# Как сделать групповую выборку файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Есть код, который выбирает 1 файл. Необходимо изменить код, чтобы можно было выбрать и использовать пути сразу нескольких файлов; чтобы их потом записать построчно в текстовый файл.

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets 
import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog


    def toFeatureAnomalies(part):

        with open('feautures.txt', 'a')as f:
            f.write(part + '\n')
            f.close()
            print(f)

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файлы данных (data.csv) ", "", "(*.csv)",
                                                options=options)

        part = None
        for _file in files:
            if 'data' in _file:
                part = _file

        if part:
            print(part)
            toFeatureAnomalies(part)
        else:
            print("Что-то пошло не так:")
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? У вас диалог уже делает групповую выборку файлов. В диалоге выделяете файлы и тот вернет их полные пути в `files`

Comment: Я пробовал, но в файл записывается только путь к последнему файлу из выделенной группы.

Comment: Потому что у вас записывание происходит после цикла. Сейчас покажу пример, немного переделав цикл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вызывать ваш код с `toFeatureAnomalies` на каждом файле из списка:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog


def toFeatureAnomalies(part):
    with open('feautures.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(part + '\n')
        print(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файлы данных (data.csv) ", "", "(*.csv)", options=options)

    for f in files:
        if 'data' in f:
            print(f)
            toFeatureAnomalies(f)
        else:
            print("Что-то пошло не так:")
```

Comment: Ок. Все получилось. Благодарю!

Comment: @СергейЕршов, кст, в конструкции `with` не нужно вызывать `close()`, когда код закончит выполнение внутри `with` для объекта `f` будет автоматически вызван `close`

Comment: Понял)) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

или так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog


def toFeatureAnomalies(part):
    with open('feautures.txt', 'w')as f:     # 'r'
        for path in part:
            f.write(path + '\n')             # read
#        f.close()
#    print(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файлы данных (*data*.csv) ", "", "(*.csv)",
                                            options=options)

    if files:
        part = []
        for _file in files:
            if 'data' in _file:           
                part.append(_file)

    if part:
        print(part)
        toFeatureAnomalies(part)
    else:
        print("Что-то пошло не так:")
```